# How to find Server Name login into SQL Server by Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a question. Few days ago i installed `SQL Server Management Stuido` with all packages in it. My `Connection string` that im using with my MVC or WebApi apps looks like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=(name here);Trusted_Connection=True;"
 }
```

I can still manage my databases by `SQL Object Explorer` in visual studio, but my question is where find my `Server Name`? Whatever i write, i cant acces to my local database server

[image]
[image]

How to get into `Management Studio`? Where i can find my `Server Name`?

Comment: (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: Its not my Server name, still the same error as above

Comment: You may want to look through this to verify you have a server instance running: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

All you need to do is to click on `Add SQL Server` button in `SQL Server Object Explorer`. Then, in `Browse` tab click Local, then on your Server. Now you can see `Server Name` Label that you can login into `Management Studio`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You said you have installed SSMS, what about the server installation?

If the server has been installed successfully, try localhost instead of localdb.  A dot(.) will also work as local host. The server name is provided while you install the server by you after selecting the named instance. If you leave it as default instance the pattern followed by sql server would be something like MSSQLSERVER......

Comment: (.), localhost and MSSQLSERVER not work in my Server name label (`Connection to Server). How to find that server name?

Comment: Did you install only SSMS and not the SERVER? If yes, install the server. SSMS is just the editor enabling the services to connect to the server which is installed. If the server is remotely hosted, SSMS alone is enough, else server has to be installed on the machine.

Comment: How to check, if i have any Server installed?

Comment: Windows -> SQL Server will give you the menu. If its not found and you have only SSMS on your machine, it is not installed. Control panel will also show the installed server details.

Comment: look into my edit, i show what i have installed on my pc

Comment: Check your services and see if you have "SQL Server" service.

Comment: To check the services click windows+R and type services.msc, you should be able to see services related to sql server if its installed